# Setting libjpeg environment variables in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, libjpeg

I am trying to build [libuvc](https://ken.tossell.net/libuvc/doc/) for my arm64 ubuntu16.04 board and I am running into this error after installing `libjpeg-dev`:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc
   used as include directory in directory /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc
   used as include directory in directory /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc
   used as include directory in directory /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc
   used as include directory in directory /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc
   used as include directory in directory /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc
   used as include directory in directory /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc
   used as include directory in directory /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

It looks like I have to set a environment variable for it. I am unfamiliar with ubuntu packaging and I don't know how to correctly set it. Any ideas?

edit-----
here's the log file:

```
The system is: Linux - 4.4.38-tegra - aarch64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/cc 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.out"

The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "/home/nvidia/dev/libuvc/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdC/a.out"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/c++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "/home/nvidia/dev/libuvc/build/CMakeFiles/3.5.1/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"

Determining if the C compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_286b1/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_286b1.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_286b1.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nvidia/dev/libuvc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_286b1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/usr/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_286b1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTC_286b1
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_286b1.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_286b1.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_286b1 -rdynamic 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nvidia/dev/libuvc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Detecting C compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_220aa/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nvidia/dev/libuvc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o
/usr/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c
Linking C executable cmTC_220aa
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc      -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o  -o cmTC_220aa -rdynamic  
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-arm64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-arm64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-arm64 --with-arch-directory=aarch64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'cmTC_220aa' '-rdynamic' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccr8x7EZ.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -export-dynamic -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -X -EL -maarch64linux --fix-cortex-a53-843419 -z relro -o cmTC_220aa /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib -L/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../.. CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nvidia/dev/libuvc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Parsed C implicit link information from above output:
  link line regex: [^( *|.*[/\])(ld|([^/\]+-)?ld|collect2)[^/\]*( |$)]
  ignore line: [Change Dir: /home/nvidia/dev/libuvc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_220aa/fast"]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/build]
  ignore line: [make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nvidia/dev/libuvc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp']
  ignore line: [Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c]
  ignore line: [Linking C executable cmTC_220aa]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/link.txt --verbose=1]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cc      -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o  -o cmTC_220aa -rdynamic  ]
  ignore line: [Using built-in specs.]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/cc]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper]
  ignore line: [Target: aarch64-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-arm64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-arm64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-arm64 --with-arch-directory=aarch64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=aarch64-linux-gnu --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  ignore line: [gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) ]
  ignore line: [COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/]
  ignore line: [LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib/:/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/]
  ignore line: [COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'cmTC_220aa' '-rdynamic' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64']
  link line: [ /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccr8x7EZ.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/ --build-id --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -export-dynamic -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -X -EL -maarch64linux --fix-cortex-a53-843419 -z relro -o cmTC_220aa /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib -L/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../.. CMakeFiles/cmTC_220aa.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/crtn.o]
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/collect2] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/liblto_plugin.so] ==> ignore
    arg [-plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper] ==> ignore
   ...
```

This is the top of the log file and I don't see anything that sticks though I am new to cmake(and c++).

Comment: Your issue is not about Ubuntu packaging (i.e. deb), but CMake